# What does `(i, &item)` mean in a for loop which uses enumerate()?

Tags: rust

I was reading Rust docs and I saw this code:

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", bytes.iter().enumerate());

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("{}", i);
        if item == b' ' {
            print!("{}", &s[0..i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    &s[..]
}


fn main() {
    let amir = String::from("amir ali ahmadi");
    first_word(&amir);
    println!("{:?}", b" ")
}
```

Why is `i` the index?

And why is `&item` the value?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate)? If you had, it should be pretty obvious: “The iterator returned yields pairs `(i, val)`, where `i` is the current index of iteration and `val` is the value returned by the iterator.”

Comment: @mcarton i just read it and Enumerate { iter: Iter([97, 109, 105, 114, 32, 97, 108, 105, 32, 97, 104, 109, 97, 100, 105]), count: 0 }
this is the output of the enumerate bout where is index???

Comment: That shows the debug representation of the enumerate object, which is what's stored internally. It doesn't store the indices; that would be a waste. Its [Iterator implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Enumerate.html#impl-Iterator) generates the indices on the fly. Click the [src link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/adapters/mod.rs.html#1161-1247) to see how the `next()` method calculates `i` each time `next()` is called.

Comment: That is just the output of the iterator's Debug implementation. `Enumerate` is an iterator in which the item type is a tuple `(usize, T)`.

Comment: The index is generated during iteration. That's what the `count` field is there for. Why would you expect all indexes to be stored in the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `enumerate()` on an iterator, you get an instance of an `Enumerate`, whose struct is defined like this:

```
pub struct Enumerate<I> {
    iter: I,
    count: usize,
}
```

In other words, `Enumerate` simply wraps the original iterator and also a `count` field which keeps track of the next index which will be fetched from the iterator. (There is a link to the source code within [the Enumerate documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Enumerate.html).)

Each time the `for` loop calls `next()` on the `Enumerate`, it executes this method:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, <I as Iterator>::Item)> {
    let a = self.iter.next()?;
    let i = self.count;
    // Possible undefined overflow.
    AddAssign::add_assign(&mut self.count, 1);
    Some((i, a))
}
```

This returns an `Option::Some` which holds a tuple `(i, a)`. The value of `i` is equal to the `count` field, so it is equal to the current iterator index. And the value of `a` is equal to the value returned by the call to `iter.next()` on the original iterator. The `add_assign` function has the effect of incrementing the `count` field value by 1.

Note that the `?` after the call to `iter.next()` means that if the iterator contains no more items then `Option::None` will be returned instead, and the method will have finished.

As pointed out in the comments to your question, when you print the debug output of an `Enumerate` instance, you will see the nested iterator and the `count` field:

```
{
    iter: Iter([97, 109, 105, 114, 32, 97, 108, 105, 32, 97, 104, 109, 97, 100, 105]),
    count: 0
}
```